# Create sequence in oracle based on grouping

Tags: oracle11g

I have data from a query(which is join of 3 tables) like

Role    Mid Tbl id  Privilege   Url

ZH  01  1   111111  docs.oracle.com/datatype.htm

RH  01  1   111110  docs.oracle.com/datatype.htm

CM  01  1   000000  docs.oracle.com/datatype.htm

CH  02  1   111111

ZH  02  1   111111

RH  02  1   111111

CM  02  1   111111

CM  03  2   000000

CH  04  2   111111

I want another extra column as sequence. The sequence should start from 1 for every distinct Tbl_id
My output should be like

Role    Mid Tbl_id  Sequence

ZH      01  1       **1**
RH      01  1       2
CM      01  1       3
CH      02  1       4
ZH      02  1       5
RH      02  1       6
CM      02  1       7
CM      03  2       **1**
CH      04  2       2

Comment: My query for getting the initial data is                                          SELECT A.*,UR.URL_NAME FROM (SELECT UM.ROLE,UM.MENU_TABLE_ID,UG.GROUP_ID,UM.PRIVILEDGE
FROM UI_ROLE_MAPPING UM 
INNER JOIN UI_GROUP_MENU_MASTER UG
ON UG.MENU_TABLE_ID = UM.MENU_TABLE_ID
WHERE UM.END_DATE='31-DEC-9999') A
INNER JOIN UI_URL_MASTER UR
ON A.MENU_TABLE_ID=UR.MENU_TABLE_ID;

Comment: you can edit your post and add your Query there